# Добавление новых значений в массив, в котором неизвестно сколько записей

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив, в нем может быть сколько угодно записей и очень часто 0 или 1. И нужно добавить еще одну запись к тем что есть. Сейчас я добавляю, но у меня добавляется одна запись и следующая запись просто затирает предыдущую и становится на ее место.
Как можно добавить, не зная ключа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поищи что-нибудь похожее на си++ библиотеку "vector", где ты создаешь объект

```
vector<typedef> name;
/*и заталкиваешь значения с помощью*/
name.push_back(smth);
/*обращение к элементам может быть либо через итераторы, либо через оператор []*/
```

Comment: А при чем тут CPP и чем ваш ответ отличается от предыдущего?)